# Insert commas into numbers

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression, text-processing

Write a program that reads a string, and inserts commas to divide large numbers in groups of 3. i.e. 10000 => 10,000. It should 'fix' incorrectly formatted numbers as described below.

- It must work for all numbers on the same line
- It should not modify numbers after a decimal point. i.e. 1234.5678 => 1,234.5678
- Leading zeros should be removed (or inserted where appropriate):

  - 00000 => 0
  - 00001234 => 1,234
  - .1234 => 0.1234
  - 00.1234 => 0.1234
  - 1000.1234 => 1,000.1234
- All non-digit characters should not be altered.
- It should correct, incorrectly placed "," characters only when followed before or after a digit:

  - 10,,00 => 1,000
  - 00,000 => 0
  - a,2 => a2
  - 2,a => 2a
  - ,a2 => ,a2
  - 0,a2 => 0a2
  - ,,, => ,,,
  - ,,,. => ,,,.
  - ,,,1 => 1
  - ,.,,1 => 0.1
- Numbers that contain multiple "." should not be treated as a number, and therefore no comma separation should be used:

  - 1..3 => 1..3
  - 1234.5678.9012 => 1234.5678.9012
  - 1234,,.5678abc.123 => 1,234.5678abc0.123
  - 1234.,.5678abc.123 => 1234.,.5678abc0.123
- Explanations to unusual cases:

  - ,,,. => ,,,. (not a number, no special meanings to ",", ".")
  - ,,,.0 => 0 (these characters are neighbouring a number and treated as such)
  - 1,,, => 1
  - ,,,1 => 1
  - ,.,,1 => 0.1 (the "." indicates decimal number, remove incorrectly placed "," in number).
  - ,.,,.1 => ,.,,.1 (not a number because multiple ".")
  - a,,,b1234 = > a,,,b1,234 (first few characters are not neighbouring a number and treated as text)

Example inputs:

```
10000
10,000
$1234.12
~$123456789.12345~
HELLO123456.99BYE
The_amount_€45678_is_$USD51805.84
5000000-1999999=3000001
!1234567.1234+1234567.1234=2469134.2468!
00000a00
0b0001234
.a.1234
00.1234
1000.1234
10,,00
00,000
a,2
2,a
,a2
0,a2
,,,
,,,.
,,,1
,.,,1
1..3
1234.5678.9012
1234,,.5678abc.123
1234.,.5678abc.123
,,,.
,,,.0
1,,,
,,,1
,.,,1
,.,,.1
a,,,b1234
```

Corresponding outputs:

```
10,000
10,000
$1,234.12
~$123,456,789.12345~
HELLO123,456.99BYE
The_amount_€45,678_is_$USD51,805.84
5,000,000-1,999,999=3,000,001
!1,234,567.1234+1,234,567.1234=2,469,134.2468!
0a0
0b1,234
.a0.1234
0.1234
1,000.1234
1,000
0
a2
2a
,a2
0a2
,,,
,,,.
1
0.1
1..3
1234.5678.9012 
1,234.5678abc0.123
1234.,.5678abc0.123
,,,.
0
1
1
0.1
,.,,.1 
a,,,b1,234
```

Code golf: shortest code wins.

Comment: What's the expected output for `00000`? Or for `10,0001`?

Comment: Another ambiguous case: 1234.9876.5678

Comment: I've VTCed as unclear until the test cases in the comments have been addressed. Please ping me once they have so I can retract my vote or cast my vote to reopen.

Comment: @Shaggy I have just edited the post with a lot more detailed information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 71 bytes

```
/[\d.,]+/_/\d/&/\..*\./^&(`,

^0+

^\B
0
'.&`\.?0+$

/^\d+/_r`\B...
,$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDNTsMwDL77LSZVBVHjxP0ZzWFCqpjEYRIHxgER2qZ0EjswpDGuO/A8PBUvUuJ0lcBSPv/k8xc7@81hu3M8DOrJ9oTPiWqU7VWsLNGFJVXH5y0C1DrxYCvQcEZxa@laJxGAqm3vO/atrYgIMIqHgbU3YI3iIk6znDiFY4iK@VVpKERHuF2uVndjlYypHpewft007u39c3dofr6@A7vZfjTRw/1NwaUuqMyh0MEu2QRbZCFlmJ30g3ryN1mk@dywH8P7cgaB7/xsupNGTwBygeivRi8rTBGiUMdtHKaQogN0KWgBRJRDAgxIgkyUQVhb5ifjnwipp0nBdS8iPTL@lyYl8t93Up5EBYn9AIiddP4C) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
/[\d.,]+/_
```

Find all runs of digits, `.`s and `,`s.

```
/\d/&
```

Ignore those with no digits.

```
/\..*\./^&
```

Ignore those with two `.`s.

```
(`
```

Process the rest of the script on each remaining match.

```
,
```

Delete all commas.

```
^0+
```

Delete all leading zeros.

```
^\B
0
```

Insert a leading zero if the number does not begin with a digit.

```
'.&`
```

If the number contains a `.`...

```
\.?0+$
```

... delete trailing zeros and any preceding `.`.

```
/^\d+/_
```

On the part of the number before the `.`...

```
r`\B...
,$&
```

Match groups of three starting from the end, but leave at least one digit at the beginning, and insert commas before each match.

Comment: 0000 returne 0,000. 10,0000 returns 10,0,00.

Comment: I suggest deleting this and VTC as unclear.

Comment: @Neil, I have just edited the post with a lot more detailed information on various cases. Thanks for your answer so far.

Comment: @Brandon I don't think I can update my Retina 0.8.2 answer for the new requirements. Would you mind if I tried using Retina 1 instead?

Comment: @Neil any language is fine. Edit as much as possible or delete and start a new answer.